# Ability to capture array of frames without having to play video, then play backwards in flash/flex client side

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, video, netstream

I've seen a few posts out there that have dealt with taking a screenshot of a playing video frame.  I'm looking for a way to play video backwards and generally move around at a frame at a time.  Ideally I'd be able to extract out frames from flash video before and after a particular i-frame.

Most importantly to this question is the ability to extract the frames, without actually playing the video.  All the solutions I've found on SO require the video to be playing, then they essentially just print the screen to a bitmap.

Is is possible in actionscript to extract out the individual video frames to enable single frame advance both forward and backward?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way, without first playing content. But... you *could* sequentially bitmapdata.draw each frame as a streamed video (not necessarily in the display list) plays, until you have one large array of bitmaps to navigate through. There's two big problems with this:

One, obviously, is that you would only have access to the frames that have already played. This might be dealt with by whatever else is happening in your app - say a user is interacting with some introduction content while the video is streaming/being captured.

The other, maybe insurmountable, problem is with memory. The reason you stream content is so that you don't have all 24 megs (or whatver) of the flv in memory at all time. This type of scenario would mean that you would have to. That being said, depending on the size / number of frames - this may not be such a big issue.

Frankly, if you decide to go this route, you'd be better breaking the video into frames outside of flash (in after effects or premier), and embedding them with the swf (or loading them individually). It would mean you would have better control over compression, at any rate.

Maybe that helps ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have an infinitely large stream of video that is possible so embedded video is definitely out of the question.  This has been a frustrating task, as I've seen this function done fine by people in .NET systems.  I wish there was lower level access on the actionscript side.

Answer (score 0):

Your combination of the parts is confusing, but...

Ability to capture array of frames:

```
bitmapData.draw(video);
```

without having to play video:

```
netStream.pause();
```

then play backwards:

```
netStream.step(-1);
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html

Comment: Doesn't bitmapData.draw require the video to be playing?  I didn't think the step would do frame, it can only go back to prior i-frame.

Comment: No, you can capture while the video is paused.  The documentation for step doesn't say anything about i-frames, just frames.

Answer (score 0):

Navigating a video backwards is no problem if you encode the video file it with a keyframe interval of 1 (that is when all frames are keyframes). That increases the size of the file but gives you the possibility to instantly jump to any frame on playback.